# "The requested resource does not support http method 'POST' - 405 response

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, ajax, asp.net-web-api2

$.http reqeust and web api both on localhost but different applications.

**angular js (in other asp.net application**)

```
 return $http({
   method: "POST",                       
   url: config.APIURL + 'Parts',
   data: {'final':'final'},
   headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
 });
```

**web api (in separate application)**

```
[HttpPost]
public Part Post(string final)
{
               ...
}
```

Error response:

> {"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method
>   'POST'."}

web api 2 - already marked with [HTTPPOST] even though not need.

My reqeust and response packet are as follow:

```
**General**
    Request URL:http://localhost/SigmaNest.WebAPI/api/Parts
    Request Method:POST
    Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed
    Remote Address:[::1]:80
    **Response Headers**
    view source
    Allow:GET
    Cache-Control:no-cache
    Content-Length:73
    Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
    Date:Tue, 10 Jan 2017 13:05:59 GMT
    Expires:-1
    Pragma:no-cache
    Server:Microsoft-IIS/10.0
    X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
    X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
    **Request Headers**
    view source
    Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
    Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
    Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
    Connection:keep-alive
    Content-Length:17
    Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
    Host:localhost
    Origin:http://localhost
    Referer:http://localhost/SigmaNest.Web/app/views/index.html
    User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
    **Request Payload**
    view source
    {final: "final"}
    final
    :
    "final"
```

can any one please help me to resolve this 405 error.

Comment: Please pass the server side code as well

Comment: its already posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.Net is struggling to match up your Ajax post to an appropriate controller action because there isn't one that matches what you're trying to call.

In this case you're trying to pass an object `{'final':'final'}` but are accepting a string. `Post(string final)` and ASP.Net cannot match this to any particular action that has `POST` enabled.

You can stringify your javascript object

```
return $http({
   method: "POST",                       
   url: config.APIURL + 'Parts',
   data: JSON.stringify({'final':'final'}), // Strinify your object
   headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
 });
```

Or, change your server side method to receive a class to match the object you're supplying. For example:

```
// DTO MyObject - .Net will ModelBind your javascript object to this when you post
public class MyObject{
  public string final {get;set;}
}
// change string here to your DTO MyObject
public Part Post(MyObject final){
      ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. :) thanks for explaination too.

Comment: You're welcome. And explanations are important :) So many people just post the code